# Unity won't slice images properly

Tags: unity

Okay, so I am very new to Game Development and I imported a .png file(made in Paint) to the assets and that file contains just a circle and an oval, not touching and far apart from each other, both of them coloured blue. When I open the sprite editor and click on splice, then select Automatic and Delete existing options and then click slice, I do not get different sprites, one containing the circle and the other containing the oval. The image isn't sliced at all. I have also set the sprite mode to Multiple, but to no avail.

Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong? The engine I am using is Unity.
[image]

This is the image.

Comment: If you are having difficulties, try to do it manually. If you don't want to do that, I think you should define the cell size for each sprite. So they couldn't be that far from each other. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity will recognize this as one sprite because it doesn't realize that white is supposed to be non-solid. Why would it? White is a color like any other. You could slice this manually in the sprite editor by dragging a rectangle over each object with the left mouse button, but that way you will end up with a circle and an oval on white rectangles.

If the white parts are meant to be transparent, then you have to use an image editor which can create PNG images with actual transparency. MSPaint can't do that, but there are lots of alternatives available which can. [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) or [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/) are some examples of alternatives which don't cost any money. [Aseprite](https://www.aseprite.org/) or [Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) are examples of paid products which some game developers think are worth their money.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded Paint.net and now unity split the picture into sprites quite easily.